# (How) can I generate with cmake a header file that include header files?

Tags: cmake

i have a project that has several header files. I want now to generate a header file that includes all project header files.

For example we have the following headers:

- a.h
- b.h
- c.h
- ext/d.h

Now I want to generate a header file that includes all header files and looks approximately like that:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"
#include "c.h"
#include "ext/d.h"
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Comment: Do you want to use that for a pre-compiled header file (.gch), or what is your usecase?

Comment: I just like to use one single header when i use a library. Like Foundation/Foundation.h in Objective-C.

Answer (score 3):

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE header_files "include/*.h")
foreach(f ${header_files})
  message("processing ${f}")
  file(RELATIVE_PATH fr "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include" ${f})
  list(APPEND incls "#include \"${fr}\"\n")
endforeach()
file(WRITE mylibheader.h ${incls})
```

Description:

- [file(GLOB_RECURSE ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file) stores all header files to the variable `header_files`.
- [file(RELATIVE_PATH ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file) determines relative path from absolute path generated by GLOB
- [list(APPEND ...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:list) stores the [c](/questions/tagged/c) include code snippet to the variable
- [file(WRITE...)](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command:file) creates the header file